# Regex to span range of -9.99 to 0 in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I feel I am very close, to my regex -9.99 through 0.

I have

```
/^[-][0-9]?(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?$/ // does not get the 0 :/
```

if I add |0 then it allows 20 30 etc...

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I have an input where user has to add value between those two numbers..

Comment: Are `-`, `-.0`, `-0` valid numbers?

Comment: It might help to break it down into sub-cases, rather than trying to do it all in one - you want a regex that matches '0' (are 0.0, .0, 0.00 also valid?) or a minus sign followed by D.DD where D is any digit (but again, are just plain D, D., .D .D, D.D also valid forms?). I'm sure it can be done, but it isn't gonna be pretty...

Comment: Can there be more than two decimal places?

Comment: I was intending two decimals only. You all think of exceptions that totally escaped me! For my purposes, the answer below is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parenthesis to make your `|0` work correctly with the `^` and `$`. Also `[-]` is the same as a literal `-`, and `\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]` :)

```
/^(-\d?(\.\d\d?)?|0)$/
```

If you're using Javascript though it's much simpler (and faster) to convert your string to a number and go from there (assuming you can allow numbers like `-3.21312` as well, otherwise you can also strip off the excess digits):

```
var str = "-8.57";
if(-10 < +str && +str <= 0){
    // Condition passed
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit of my answer I forgot this `-` and +1 for you for a better answer including explanation.

Comment: wish I would have known.. I have been slaving over regex and nearly done now. Thanks!

Comment: @mattyd No problemo! :) In general if you're thinking of something as a number it's better to convert it to a number either using `+` which is shorthand for `NUmber("-8.57")` or `parseInt("-8.57", 10)` or `parseFloat("-8.57")`. Then do your work with it as a number. Regex is good at strings, but not very good when you want to think of the string as another type.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you are after but since you deal with numbers why don't you do (where `x` is your number):

```
if(x <= 0 && x >= -9.99)
   console.log("OK");
```